# Store multiple objects in one json geometry in Three.js

Tags: javascript, json, three.js

You can easily store a BufferGeometry as json and load it using BufferGeometryLoader:

```
{
  "metadata": {
    "version": 3,
    "type": "Geometry",
    "normal": 30,
    "position": 30,
    "generator": "io_three"
  },
  "data": {
    "index": {
      "array": [ 0, 1, 2, 3, …],
      "type": "Uint16Array",
      "itemSize": 1
    },
    "attributes": {
      "normal": {
        "array": [ -1, 0, 0, -1, …],
        "type": "Float32Array",
        "itemSize": 3
      },
      "position": {
        "array": [ -1, 1, 1, -1, …],
        "type": "Float32Array",
        "itemSize": 3
      }
    },
    "groups": [
      {
        "count": 48,
        "start": 0,
        "materialIndex": 0
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And to load it you may use the following code:

```
var loader = new THREE.BufferGeometryLoader();
loader.load(
'JS/Sample1.json',
function (geometry) {
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial({}));
    scene.add(mesh);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
);
```

Now the question is storing more than one geometry in the json format. Is it possible to do so. If yes, is there any instruction or sample for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`THREE.BufferGeometryLoader` is only able to load a single instance of `BufferGeometry` per request. If you don't want to implement a custom solution, you have to load each geometry with a separate call of `load()`. So something like:

```
var loader = new THREE.BufferGeometryLoader();
loader.load( 'JS/Sample1.json', geometry => {...} );
loader.load( 'JS/Sample2.json', geometry => {...} );
loader.load( 'JS/Sample3.json', geometry => {...} );
```

An alternative would be the usage of the [Object/Scene JSON format](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/JSON-Object-Scene-format-4) that is implemented by `THREE.ObjectLoader`. However, this format is intended to represent 3D objects like meshes, lines and point clouds and the respective object hierarchy. So just serialize/deserialize an array of geometry objects is not possible. You have to work on object/scene level.

Comment: Thanks, In the project, there would be 80 geometry each has maximum 20 vertices. Do you think it takes a long time to load?

Comment: AFAIK, there is a maximum amount of parallel network request of browsers. So it will more slower than loading a single file. Another option might be to push all JSON files into a single zip archive, load this file and then use `JSZip` to unpack it. You can then try to directly invocate `BufferGeometryLoader.parse()` with the single JSON data. However, I have not tested this so I'm not sure this works...